# CSS3 Card Flip w/Keyframes Not Working

Tags: javascript, css

> This CSS3 Cardflip with Keyframes is almost working the way I want it except for one problem. The front face reappears after flipping over. The back face is transparent. That's the way I want it . You can see the below canvas when it flips over, but then it should stay flipped over. The front face reappears at the end of the animation and I can't figure out why?

```js
 window.onload = function(){
 
  var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
  var parentWidth = parent.offsetWidth;
  var parentHeight = parent.offsetHeight;
  
  //belowCanvas
  var belowCanvas = document.getElementById('belowCanvas');
  var belowCtx = belowCanvas.getContext('2d');

  //canvas
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  //blankCanvas
  var blankCanvas = document.getElementById('blankCanvas');
  var blankCtx = blankCanvas.getContext('2d');
  
  blankCanvas.width = canvas.width = belowCanvas.width = 170;
  blankCanvas.height = canvas.height = belowCanvas.height = 255;
  
  //card flip white
  ctx.rect(0,0,parentWidth,parentHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  
  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
   window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
    function( callback ){
     window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
  })();
  
  var card = document.getElementById('card');
 
  setTimeout(function() {
   requestAnimFrame(function() {
    card.classList.add('flip');
   });
  }, 680);
 };
```

```css
   #belowCanvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  z-index: -1;
  
 background: rgb(254,255,232); /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,232,1) 0%, rgba(214,219,191,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(254,255,232,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(214,219,191,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,232,1) 0%,rgba(214,219,191,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,232,1) 0%,rgba(214,219,191,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,232,1) 0%,rgba(214,219,191,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(254,255,232,1) 0%,rgba(214,219,191,1) 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#feffe8', endColorstr='#d6dbbf',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


 }

 #parent {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }

 .container{
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  -ms-perspective: 1000px;
  -o-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 255px;
  
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }

 #card{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }

 .front, .back{

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  position: absolute;

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
 }

 #card .back {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
 } 

 .flip{
  -webkit-animation: flipCard 1s;
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes flipCard {
   0% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   10% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   20% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112960000000001px 4.112960000000001px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   30% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.88704px 16.88704px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(0.17135717260665195deg);
   }

   40% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(5.4834295234128625deg);
   }

   50% {
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.15)
  rotateY(41.639792943416424deg);
   }

   60% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(138.36020705658356deg);
   }

   70% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.887040000000006px 16.887040000000006px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(174.51657047658713deg);
   }

   80% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112959999999997px 4.112959999999997px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(179.82864282739334deg);
   }

   90% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }

   100% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }


 }

 @-moz-keyframes flipCard {
   0% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   10% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   20% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112960000000001px 4.112960000000001px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   30% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.88704px 16.88704px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(0.17135717260665195deg);
   }

   40% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(5.4834295234128625deg);
   }

   50% {
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.15)
  rotateY(41.639792943416424deg);
   }

   60% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(138.36020705658356deg);
   }

   70% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.887040000000006px 16.887040000000006px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(174.51657047658713deg);
   }

   80% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112959999999997px 4.112959999999997px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(179.82864282739334deg);
   }

   90% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }

   100% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }


 }

 @-ms-keyframes flipCard {
   0% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   10% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   20% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112960000000001px 4.112960000000001px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   30% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.88704px 16.88704px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(0.17135717260665195deg);
   }

   40% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(5.4834295234128625deg);
   }

   50% {
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.15)
  rotateY(41.639792943416424deg);
   }

   60% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(138.36020705658356deg);
   }

   70% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.887040000000006px 16.887040000000006px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(174.51657047658713deg);
   }

   80% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112959999999997px 4.112959999999997px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(179.82864282739334deg);
   }

   90% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }

   100% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }


 }

 @-o-keyframes flipCard {
   0% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   10% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   20% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112960000000001px 4.112960000000001px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   30% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.88704px 16.88704px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(0.17135717260665195deg);
   }

   40% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(5.4834295234128625deg);
   }

   50% {
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.15)
  rotateY(41.639792943416424deg);
   }

   60% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(138.36020705658356deg);
   }

   70% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.887040000000006px 16.887040000000006px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(174.51657047658713deg);
   }

   80% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112959999999997px 4.112959999999997px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(179.82864282739334deg);
   }

   90% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }

   100% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }


 }

 @keyframes flipCard {
   0% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   10% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   20% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112960000000001px 4.112960000000001px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   30% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.88704px 16.88704px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(0.17135717260665195deg);
   }

   40% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(5.4834295234128625deg);
   }

   50% {
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.15)
  rotateY(41.639792943416424deg);
   }

   60% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(138.36020705658356deg);
   }

   70% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.887040000000006px 16.887040000000006px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(174.51657047658713deg);
   }

   80% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112959999999997px 4.112959999999997px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(179.82864282739334deg);
   }

   90% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }

   100% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }


 }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Title</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="patternizer.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  

  <div id="parent">
   <canvas id="belowCanvas"></canvas>
   <div class="container">
    <div id="card">
     <div class="front">
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
     </div>
     <div class="back">
      <canvas id="blankCanvas"></canvas>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties that you set during the animation disappear once the animation is over. That is the standard way of working.

To leave the front face hidden, you have 2 posibilities

1. Specify **forwards** as the **animation-fill-mode** property. that makes the last keyframe *stay*
2. Set the properties that you want to stay in the final class (*my favourite*). In your case, the *flip* class

   ```
   .flip{
       -webkit-animation: flipCard 1s;
       transform: rotateY(180deg);
   }
   ```

```js
 window.onload = function(){
 
  var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
  var parentWidth = parent.offsetWidth;
  var parentHeight = parent.offsetHeight;
  
  //belowCanvas
  var belowCanvas = document.getElementById('belowCanvas');
  var belowCtx = belowCanvas.getContext('2d');

  //canvas
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  //blankCanvas
  var blankCanvas = document.getElementById('blankCanvas');
  var blankCtx = blankCanvas.getContext('2d');
  
  blankCanvas.width = canvas.width = belowCanvas.width = 170;
  blankCanvas.height = canvas.height = belowCanvas.height = 255;
  
  //card flip white
  ctx.rect(0,0,parentWidth,parentHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  
  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
   window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
    function( callback ){
     window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
  })();
  
  var card = document.getElementById('card');
 
  setTimeout(function() {
   requestAnimFrame(function() {
    card.classList.add('flip');
   });
  }, 680);
 };
```

```css
   #belowCanvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  z-index: -1;
  
 background: rgb(254,255,232); /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,232,1) 0%, rgba(214,219,191,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(254,255,232,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(214,219,191,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,232,1) 0%,rgba(214,219,191,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,232,1) 0%,rgba(214,219,191,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,232,1) 0%,rgba(214,219,191,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(254,255,232,1) 0%,rgba(214,219,191,1) 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#feffe8', endColorstr='#d6dbbf',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


 }

 #parent {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }

 .container{
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  -ms-perspective: 1000px;
  -o-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 255px;
  
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }

 #card{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }

 .front, .back{

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  position: absolute;

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
 }

 #card .back {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
 } 

 .flip{
  -webkit-animation: flipCard 1s;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes flipCard {
   0% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   10% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   20% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112960000000001px 4.112960000000001px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   30% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.88704px 16.88704px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(0.17135717260665195deg);
   }

   40% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(5.4834295234128625deg);
   }

   50% {
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.15)
  rotateY(41.639792943416424deg);
   }

   60% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(138.36020705658356deg);
   }

   70% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.887040000000006px 16.887040000000006px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(174.51657047658713deg);
   }

   80% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112959999999997px 4.112959999999997px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(179.82864282739334deg);
   }

   90% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }

   100% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }


 }

 @-moz-keyframes flipCard {
   0% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   10% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   20% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112960000000001px 4.112960000000001px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   30% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.88704px 16.88704px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(0.17135717260665195deg);
   }

   40% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(5.4834295234128625deg);
   }

   50% {
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.15)
  rotateY(41.639792943416424deg);
   }

   60% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(138.36020705658356deg);
   }

   70% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.887040000000006px 16.887040000000006px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(174.51657047658713deg);
   }

   80% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112959999999997px 4.112959999999997px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(179.82864282739334deg);
   }

   90% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }

   100% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }


 }

 @-ms-keyframes flipCard {
   0% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   10% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   20% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112960000000001px 4.112960000000001px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   30% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.88704px 16.88704px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(0.17135717260665195deg);
   }

   40% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(5.4834295234128625deg);
   }

   50% {
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.15)
  rotateY(41.639792943416424deg);
   }

   60% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(138.36020705658356deg);
   }

   70% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.887040000000006px 16.887040000000006px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(174.51657047658713deg);
   }

   80% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112959999999997px 4.112959999999997px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(179.82864282739334deg);
   }

   90% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }

   100% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -ms-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }


 }

 @-o-keyframes flipCard {
   0% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   10% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   20% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112960000000001px 4.112960000000001px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   30% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.88704px 16.88704px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(0.17135717260665195deg);
   }

   40% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(5.4834295234128625deg);
   }

   50% {
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.15)
  rotateY(41.639792943416424deg);
   }

   60% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(138.36020705658356deg);
   }

   70% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.887040000000006px 16.887040000000006px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(174.51657047658713deg);
   }

   80% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112959999999997px 4.112959999999997px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(179.82864282739334deg);
   }

   90% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }

   100% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -o-transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }


 }

 @keyframes flipCard {
   0% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   10% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   20% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112960000000001px 4.112960000000001px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(0deg);
   }

   30% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.88704px 16.88704px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(0.17135717260665195deg);
   }

   40% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(5.4834295234128625deg);
   }

   50% {
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.15)
  rotateY(41.639792943416424deg);
   }

   60% {
  box-shadow: 0px 19.90272px 19.90272px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.149232)
  rotateY(138.36020705658356deg);
   }

   70% {
  box-shadow: 0px 16.887040000000006px 16.887040000000006px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.125424)
  rotateY(174.51657047658713deg);
   }

   80% {
  box-shadow: 0px 4.112959999999997px 4.112959999999997px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.024576)
  rotateY(179.82864282739334deg);
   }

   90% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1.0972799999999998px 1.0972799999999998px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1.000768)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }

   100% {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform:
  scale(1)
  rotateY(180deg);
   }


 }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Title</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="patternizer.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  

  <div id="parent">
   <canvas id="belowCanvas"></canvas>
   <div class="container">
    <div id="card">
     <div class="front">
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
     </div>
     <div class="back">
      <canvas id="blankCanvas"></canvas>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add `perspective: 1000px;` on `#parent`.

Comment: Hi Jorge. I just tried that. It doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS animation call looks like this:

`.flip{ -webkit-animation: flipCard 1s; }`

You need to tell it not to reset, which you can do by passing an [animation iteration count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_values_syntax#syntax-single-animation-iteration-count):

`.flip{ -webkit-animation: flipCard 1s 1; }`